# Bash "Join" with two columns

Tags: command-line, bioinformatics, join

I have two files:

```
1_file.txt:
ChrX 129759713 A G
ChrX 129760010 C T
ChrX 129762238 C G
ChrX 129762448 A G
ChrX 129762803 A C
ChrX 129763441 C A
ChrX 129764931 T C
ChrX 129767696 C T
ChrX 129818213 C T
ChrX 129841336 T C

2_files.txt:
Chr29 129841336 T C
Chr29 129845233 A G
Chr29 129852688 T C
Chr29 129871602 G T
Chr29 129872683 T C
ChrX 129875545 C A
ChrX 129876975 A G
ChrX 129879796 G A
ChrX 129880521 T C
ChrX 129759713 A G
ChrX 129760010 C T
ChrX 129762238 C G
ChrX 129762448 A G
ChrX 129762803 A C
ChrX 129763441 C A
```

I want to join both files into one by field ONE and TWO

```
The answer
ChrX 129759713 A G
ChrX 129760010 C T
ChrX 129762238 C G
ChrX 129762448 A G
ChrX 129762803 A C
ChrX 129763441 C A
```

Any ideas how can i do it using join or awk?

Comment: Please provide a **testable** sample of inputs + desired output. There don't appear to be any joinable cases in the input you have provided.

Comment: Sure, it should be clearer. Here it is

Comment: Do you actually want to join or do you just want common lines from both files based on the first and second columns?

Comment: I want some kind of INNER JOIN, but finally, we want to get lines which are on both files

Answer (score 2):

Are you missing rows in the second file?  I don't see one with "T G" or "A T".  To my knowledge, `join` doesn't accept two fields, you simply join two fields using sed.  Here's an example for your specific example:

`join -j 1 <(cat 1_file.txt | sed "s/ /_/")  <(cat 2_files.txt | sed "s/ /_/")`

Comment: Thanks for answer. I was looking for an example with join with two fields...but ineffectively. But if u tell that join isn't works, I trust you :D

Answer (score 2):

With awk, you could use

```bsh
awk '
    NR == FNR          {f1[$1,$2] = $0; next}
    $1 SUBSEP $2 in f1 {print f1[$1,$2], $3, $4}
' 1_file.txt 2_files.txt
```

```
ChrX 129759713 A G A G
ChrX 129760010 C T C T
ChrX 129762238 C G C G
ChrX 129762448 A G A G
ChrX 129762803 A C A C
ChrX 129763441 C A C A
```

For details about awk syntax and generally how it works, see [the awk info page on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info)

Here:

- `NR == FNR` is that condition that is true only for the lines of the first file being processed. In the block, we are storing each line in an array, keyed by the first 2 fields. See [the gawk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Auto_002dset.html) for the meaning of the variables.
- in the array key, using a comma joins the fields using the builtin SUBSEP variable ([reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multidimensional.html))
- the `$1 SUBSEP $2 in f1` condition is true if, for a line in the second file, the first and second fields also appeared in the first file.

Comment: Really nice answer. Could you explaint it?